# The set $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0,(1+x^2)\tan2x=x\}$ is countably infinite

Tags: cardinals

The set $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0,(1+x^2)\tan2x=x\}$ is

1. Empty
2. Finite
3. Countably infinite
4. Uncountable

I have plotted the graph and see that the required set is countably infinite. How to prove this fact?

Comment: **Hint :** how many solutions the equation $(1+x^2)\tan(2x)=x$ on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{k\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ ?